# UITableView - animate insert rows in Xamarin

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What I basically want to achieve is the following: I am using a TableView where I'm dynamically adding and deleting rows. It works fine with using `TableView.Insert(index, Cell)` in Xamarin.Forms

However it doesn't look really pretty and I'd like to achieve a [similar animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LSpp.jpg) as you can find in the native iOS contacts app.

I have a custom iOS renderer for my `TableView` and also for my `TableViewModel`. However I can't find any way to override the `Insert()` function in my renderer to add an animation. I know that it's possible to add an animation with the native UITableView `InsertRows(NSIndexPath[], UITableViewAnimation)`  but i don't really understand how i would use that function inside my Xamarin.Forms custom renderer, as I'm not adding the Rows there, i'm rather adding cells in my shared code?

Comment: You could use MessagingCenter to send message from forms to custom renderer when you want to insert a row . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT thats a good idea. I've been using messaging center a lot i really like it. But then i would have to build the cells natively for UITableview instead of using a Xamarin.Forms `ViewCell` i suppose?

Comment: Of course it is another option .

Comment: is there any option inside of xamarin.forms to animate inserting into a tableview?

Comment: We could not set the style of insert animation in Forms directly. You could search if there are some third part plugin which can implement it .